# How to connect button to the unwindSegue? Swift, Xcode

Tags: xcode, unwind-segue

I'm facing a problem that I can't connect the button to the unwind segue.

I made a simple application with three controllers.
[image]

The unwind segue code is located in Table View Controller.

```
@IBAction func unwindToTableViewController(_ unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        let sourceViewController = unwindSegue.source
    }
```

A segue has been implemented from the Add button of Table View Controller to the View controller. It is a Push type.

There is a Save button as Bar Button Item in the View Controller.

When I try to drag a connection from Save button to the Exit icon of the View Controller, the context menu does not open indicating the unwind segue.
[image]

At the same time, if I simply hover the cursor over the Exit icon, the unwind segue is visible (the first screen). But if I try to drag the connection from the button, it’s not there (the second screen).

It seems that this problem is caused by some glitches in different versions of Xcode.

The example of application given here was created in XCode 15.3. I have tested the same application on another computer, where the version of Xcode is 13.4.1. There, when I try to drag a connection from the Save button to the Exit icon, a context menu appears with the name of the unwind method.

But the problem didn't end there because after the connection is established, the button does not work and the View Controller does not dismiss.

I can't understand why. It worked before.

How to fix it? Any ideas will be appreciated!

Comment: From the information you provided, it looks like you're doing everything correctly, so perhaps, the problem is somewhere else what you didn't mention. I would start with double-checking that everything is set according to Apple's instructions: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/resource_management/dismissing_a_view_controller_with_an_unwind_segue.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution!

It needs to right-click the Exit icon, then left-click and drag from circle to the Button, and then choose the 'action'.

After that the connection will be established and the unwind method will be work.
[image]